# Uwsgi starts from root but not as a service

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I have nginx + uwsgi setup for flask website.

thats my nginx

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name _;

location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/site/app/static/;
}

location / {
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:5080;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
}
```

And here is my uwsgi config.xml

```
<uwsgi>
<socket>127.0.0.1:5080</socket>
<autoload/>
<daemonize>/var/log/uwsgi_webapp.log</daemonize>
<pythonpath>/var/www/site/</pythonpath>
<module>run:app</module>
<plugins>python27</plugins>
<virtualenv>/var/www/venv/</virtualenv>
<processes>1</processes>
<enable-threads/>
<master />
<harakiri>60</harakiri>
<max-requests>2000</max-requests>
<limit-as>512</limit-as>
<reload-on-as>256</reload-on-as>
<reload-on-rss>192</reload-on-rss>
<no-orphans/>
<vacuum/>
</uwsgi>
```

When I trying to start uwsgi service (`service uwsgi start`) it says ok but there is no uwsgi process and I see the following in the log:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 1.0.3-debian (64bit) on [Fri Oct 25 00:43:13 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 17 July 2012 02:26:54
current working directory: /
writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/gsk/pid
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
limiting address space of processes...
your process address space limit is 536870912 bytes (512 MB)
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be         rejected on post-unbuffered webservers *** 
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:5080 fd 6
bind(): Permission denied [socket.c line 107]
```

However when I start uwsgi as a root

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:5080 --module run --callab app --harakiri 15 --harakiri-verbose --logto2 tmp/uwsgi.log
```

It starts just fine and after restarting nginx I can access website.

What can be an issue ?

Comment: fwiw upgrade as soon as possible, anything older than uWSGI 1.4 is unmaintained, utterly old (more than 2 years) and with tons of known bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that's really stupid. I spend several hours trying to figure that out and I found a reason right after I posted this. 
There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/uwsgi/+bug/781226) which made me try to add uid and gid to config:

```
<uwsgi>
<socket>127.0.0.1:5080</socket>
<autoload/>
<daemonize>/var/log/uwsgi_webapp.log</daemonize>
<pythonpath>/var/www/site/</pythonpath>
<module>run:app</module>
<plugins>python27</plugins>
<virtualenv>/var/www/gsk/</virtualenv>
<processes>1</processes>
<uid>www-data</uid>
<gid>www-data</gid>
<enable-threads/>
<master />
<harakiri>60</harakiri>
<max-requests>2000</max-requests>
<limit-as>512</limit-as>
<reload-on-as>256</reload-on-as>
<reload-on-rss>192</reload-on-rss>
<no-orphans/>
<vacuum/>
</uwsgi>
```

After adding those, it started and after restarting nginx it just works.